# Can numpy add the second dim automatically when reshaping?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I was wondering if numpy can supply the second dim automatically, because I don't want to calculate everytime, for example:

```
a1 = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],[ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11]])
a2 = np.reshape(a1,(3, a1.shape[0] * a1.shape[1] / 3))
```

However, if you use `a2 = np.reshape(a1, (3, ))`
it shows error:

> cannot reshape array of size 12 into shape (3,)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-1` for the extra dimension:

```
a2 = np.reshape(a1,(3, -1))
```

Or a little simpler

```
a2 = a1.reshape(3,-1)
```